# Upgrading eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

While upgrading from Eclipse 4.4.1 to 4.5, I found plugin com.eclipse.update.core plugin missing which contributes to updating sites but as per eclipse, this plugin has been removed in 4.8. How to know the exact details to know the missing plugins.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. That plugin was last in 3.8 (not 4.8) and was never in 4.4.1 or 4.5

Comment: Hi,

We are trying to upgrade our Eclipse RCP application from 4.4.1 to 4.5 and so on following the upgrade path to come to the latest. While upgrading to 4.5, I see plugin org.eclipse.update.core is missing which we were using in 4..4.1. So my question how to know which dependent plugin got removed and what is the alternate to attaining that functionality. I didn't find any documents on which plugins fill the gap for org.eclipse.update.core plugins to and how to attain this functionality .

Comment: Eclipse 4 uses the p2 system for updates - org.eclipse.equinox.p2.xxxx plugins